# How to mock Server Variables using NSubstitute

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit, nsubstitute

I have the following method to get a user's IP address:

```cs
public string GetUserIpAddress(HttpContext context)
{
    var ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
        if (addresses.Length != 0)
        {
            return addresses[0];
        }
    }
    return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test for this but am struggling to do so (using NSubstitute and NUnit). I have read other articles and so far this is my attempt:

```cs
var request = Substitute.For<HttpRequestBase>();
request.ServerVariables.Returns(new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
{
    { "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR", "value here" }
});

var httpContext = Substitute.For<HttpContextBase>();
httpContext.Request.Returns(request);

var helper = new UserIpAddressHelper();
var result = helper.GetUserIpAddress(httpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context);
```

The error is that the result is returning null when I want it to be configured properly with the server variables above.

Comment: https://techblog.dorogin.com/asp-net-httpcontext-vs-httpcontextbase-dc7ac82b0ff1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpRequestBase` has been created specifically to be testable, because it is abstract and can therefore be overridden by a mocking framework.

If you want `GetUserIpAddress` to be testable, have it accept a `HttpContextBase` instance:

```
public string GetUserIpAddress(HttpContextBase context)
```

If it needs to be called from code that uses `HttpContext` that can be wrapped:

```
HttpContext context;
var ipAddress = GetUserIpAddress(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
```